# Nested query not giving desired results

Tags: sql

I am trying to execute two queries in a nest but the below query is not giving any o/p

```
select Object_name from IM_top where Id_number in
(select t.Id_number from IM_top t,IM_alarm_state a,IM_network_element n,Related_to_AH_id r
where t.Id_number = a.Id_number and t.Id_number = n.Id_number and t.Id_number *= r.Id_from
and t.Object_class like 'IM_top/IM_alarm_state/IM_network_element%') where Object_name not in (select substring(object,LEN(object)-CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(object)) + 2,CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(object)) + 1  ) from fmadb_1_1..FMA_alarm_text_route )
```

When i run these queries individually the first query returns 2206 rows

```
select Object_name from IM_top where Id_number in
(select t.Id_number from IM_top t,IM_alarm_state a,IM_network_element n,Related_to_AH_id r
where t.Id_number = a.Id_number and t.Id_number = n.Id_number and t.Id_number *= r.Id_from
and t.Object_class like 'IM_top/IM_alarm_state/IM_network_element%')
```

and second query returns 184 rows

```
select substring(object,LEN(object)-CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(object)) + 2,CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(object)) + 1  ) from fmadb_1_1..FMA_alarm_text_route
```

I am expecting the difference of 2206-184 which is 2022 rows when i run nested query but o/p it gives is 0 rows.

Any workaround?

Comment: Could be that all `Object_name` values appear on the second query?

Comment: No second query has 184 Object names and first has 2206 Object names. Using nested query i am expecting the difference of 2206-184 rows

Comment: But does first query have any `Object_name` that doesn't appear on second one? (It has more, yes, but could be repeated)

Comment: Yes our purpose is to find objects that doesn't matches with the object_names from first query as first query is  returning 2206 rows and second is returning 184 rows there are 2022 object_name that are not present in 2nd query which we want to print out

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery returns a NULL, which always results in an empty answer set:

> a NOT IN (1,NULL)

is logically equivalent to

> a <> 1 and a <> NULL

which resolves to

> TRUE/FALSE AND UNKNOWN

and finally results in

> UNKNOWN

for any row.

Add a WHERE-condition to remove the NULLs or better change the NOT IN to a NOT EXISTS.

Comment: When i run the query and subquery individually it returns the rows but no results are returned when these queries are combined

Comment: As I wrote: check the subquery for NULLs and remove them with a WHERE condition.

Comment: Subquery is not returning null it is just showing 0 rows affected

Comment: The subquery is the query returning 184 rows, this returns NULL.

Comment: Btw, what's your DBMS? The "*=" in a join-condition reminds me of some very old proprietary Outer Join syntax (DB2/SQL Server? How many rows are retuned by chaning it to an IN?

Comment: Our DBMS is sybase adaptive server 15.0.

Comment: First query returns 2206 rows when executed and second returns 184 rows. Chaining both of them are returning 0 rows that is where the problem lies

Comment: You still didn't answer if the 2nd query returns NULLs.

Comment: No 2nd query doesn't returns NULL

Comment: Does an IN instead of NOT IN return rows? Try joining both tables with an Outer Join to see which values don't match.

Comment: Did you try the Outer Join or NOT EXISTS?

Answer (score 0):

You have used Two `Where` Clause instead of `AND`

Try this

```
select Object_name from IM_top where Id_number in
(select t.Id_number from IM_top t,IM_alarm_state a,IM_network_element n,Related_to_AH_id r
where t.Id_number = a.Id_number and t.Id_number = n.Id_number and t.Id_number *= r.Id_from
and t.Object_class like 'IM_top/IM_alarm_state/IM_network_element%') AND Object_name not in (select substring(object,LEN(object)-CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(object)) + 2,CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(object)) + 1  ) from fmadb_1_1..FMA_alarm_text_route )
```

Hope this help you

Comment: even after using AND results are same 0 rows

Comment: even after using AND results are same 0 rows

Comment: Object_name belongs to which table

Comment: If you're still getting 0 rows, it might mean that the object names returned by your subquery are not available in the `IM_TOP` table. Try searching for any one object name retuned by your subquery in `IM_TOP`

Comment: I have matched a single object with subquery and it gives desired results but not with all the objects